kgdb gives confusing variable content
I'm debugging riscv linux kernel running on a sbc with kgdb. After gdb is connected to linux kernel with kgdb enabled, print command in gdb produces confusing result.
For example, right after statement host = kzalloc(sizeof(struct mmc_host) + extra, GFP_KERNEL); is executed, p *host produces the following result. But as per kzalloc comment, everything of this host struct should be 0.
There are other examples where the content of variables is way off. Is this expected when we use kgdb to debug linux kernel?
>>> p *host
$38 = {
  parent = 0x650000000000636d,
  class_dev = {
    kobj = {
      name = 0x20642520726f7272 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x20642520726f7272>,
      entry = {
        next = 0x6974736575716572,
        prev = 0x757461747320676e
      },
      parent = 0x4300000000000a73,
      kset = 0x6375747320647261,
      ktype = 0x6f7277206e69206b,
      sd = 0x657461747320676e,
      kref = {
        refcount = {
          refs = {
            counter = 1931812897
          }
        }
      },
      state_initialized = 0,
      state_in_sysfs = 0,
      state_add_uevent_sent = 0,
      state_remove_uevent_sent = 0,
      uevent_suppress = 0
    },
    parent = 0x782325203a737574,
    p = 0x660000000000000a,
    init_name = 0x6f725f6563726f <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x6f725f6563726f>,
    type = 0x7200000000000000,
    bus = 0x755f6b636f6c5f6f,
    driver = 0x78656e5f6c69746e,
    platform_data = 0x5f7265776f705f74,
    driver_data = 0x100000000006e6f,
    mutex = {
      owner = {
        counter = 2325059501578864179
      },
      wait_lock = {
        {
          rlock = {
            raw_lock = {<No data fields>}
          }
        }
      },
      wait_list = {
        next = 0x25000000000a6425,
        prev = 0x1000a786c6c3830
      }
    },
    links = {
      suppliers = {
        next = 0x3a6b6c62636d6d33,
        prev = 0x6e20646c756f6320
      },
      consumers = {
        next = 0x736967657220746f,
        prev = 0x424d505220726574
      },
      needs_suppliers = {
        next = 0x7079742073756220,
        prev = 0x100000000000a65
      },
      defer_hook = {
        next = 0x3a6b6c62636d6d33,
        prev = 0x2064656c69616620
      },
      need_for_probe = 116,
      status = 1668246636
    },
    power = {
      power_state = {
        event = 543519841
      },
      can_wakeup = 0,
      async_suspend = 1,
      in_dpm_list = false,
      is_prepared = false,
      is_suspended = true,
      is_noirq_suspended = true,
      is_late_suspended = true,
      no_pm = false,
      early_init = false,
      direct_complete = false,
      driver_flags = 1919443744,
      lock = {
        {
          rlock = {
            raw_lock = {<No data fields>}
          }
        }
      },
      should_wakeup = 0,
      subsys_data = 0xa6e6f69676572,
      set_latency_tolerance = 0x100000000000000,
      qos = 0x3a6b6c62636d6d36
    },
    pm_domain = 0x2520676e69737520,
    pins = 0x73726f6e696d2064,
    dma_mask = 0x7665642072657020,
    coherent_dma_mask = 2666130979577750377,
    bus_dma_limit = 7286934618062731891,
    dma_range_map = 0xa642520726f7272,
    dma_parms = 0x2500000000000000,
    dma_pools = {
      next = 0x2061746164203a73,
      prev = 0x642520726f727265
    },
    dma_mem = 0x10000000000000a,
    cma_area = 0x636f4c203a732536,
    archdata = {<No data fields>},
    of_node = 0x6f6f6220676e696b,
    fwnode = 0x7469747261702074,
    devt = 544108393,
    id = 1965059954,
    devres_lock = {
      {
        rlock = {
          raw_lock = {<No data fields>}
        }
      }
    },
    devres_head = {
      next = 0x78656e206c69746e,
      prev = 0x207265776f702074
    },
    class = 0x1000000000a6e6f,
    groups = 0x636572203a732533,
    release = 0x616620797265766f,
    iommu_group = 0x6e000a2164656c69,
    iommu = 0x642065726f6d206f,
    offline_disabled = true,
    offline = false,
    of_node_reused = true,
    state_synced = false,
    dma_coherent = false
  },
  index = 1986076787,
  ops = 0x6d0000000a656c62,
  pwrseq = 0x2575256b6c62636d,
  f_min = 115,
  f_max = 671088640,
  f_init = 2715506,
  f_src = 1828716544,
  ocr_avail = 1667195757,
  ocr_avail_sdio = 1819307375,
  ocr_avail_sd = 6648933,
  ocr_avail_mmc = 16777216,
  ws = 0x2064656c69614633,
  max_current_330 = 1663070068,
  max_current_300 = 1952540018,
  max_current_180 = 1835868261,
  caps = 1868767331,
  caps2 = 1701605485,
  fixed_drv_type = 1852795252,
  pm_caps = 1919907616,
  max_seg_size = 1702195563,
  max_segs = 25973,
  unused = 0,
  max_req_size = 16777216,
  max_blk_size = 980624694,
  max_blk_count = 544417056,
  max_busy_timeout = 622883621,
  lock = {
    {
      rlock = {
        raw_lock = {<No data fields>}
      }
    }
  },
  ios = {
    clock = 1931812979,
    vdd = 10,
    power_delay_ms = 16777216,
    bus_mode = 51 '3',
    chip_select = 37 '%',
    power_mode = 115 's',
    bus_width = 58 ':',
    timing = 32 ' ',
    signal_voltage = 99 'c',
    drv_type = 111 'o',
    enhanced_strobe = 117
  },
  use_spi_crc = 0,
  claimed = 0,
  bus_dead = 1,
  doing_init_tune = 1,
  can_retune = 0,
  doing_retune = 1,
  retune_now = 1,
  retune_paused = 0,
  use_blk_mq = 0,
  retune_crc_disable = 0,
  can_dma_map_merge = 1,
  rescan_disable = 1629516911,
  rescan_entered = 1663067236,
  need_retune = 1634885992,
  hold_retune = 1919251555,
  retune_period = 1986356256,
  retune_timer = {
    entry = {
      next = 0x10000000a656369,
      pprev = 0x207325203a732536
    },
    expires = 7598824234099438373,
    function = 0x207525206e6f6974,
    flags = 539783973
  },
  trigger_card_event = 100,
  card = 0x10000000a296425,
  wq = {
    lock = {
      {
        rlock = {
          raw_lock = {<No data fields>}
        }
      }
    },
    head = {
      next = 0x207325203a732536,
      prev = 0x6974726170207325
    }
  },
  claimer = 0x207525206e6f6974,
  claim_cnt = 684837,
  default_ctx = {
    task = 0x25006473635f7478
  },
  detect = {
    work = {
      data = {
        counter = 8223649134899378803
      },
      entry = {
        next = 0x20797265766f6365,
        prev = 0x25000a7472617473
      },
      func = 0x7220455143203a73
    },
    timer = {
      entry = {
        next = 0x20797265766f6365,
        pprev = 0x100000a656e6f64
      },
      expires = 7165029233473037619,
      function = 0x6f6f6220676e696b,
      flags = 1634738292
    },
    wq = 0x75206f72206e6f69,
    cpu = 1818850414
  },
  detect_change = 1869619316,
  slot = {
    cd_irq = 1713401455,
    cd_wake_enabled = 97,
    handler_priv = 0x1000a6425203a64
  },
  bus_ops = 0x6b6e75203a732533,
  bus_refs = 1853321070,
  sdio_irqs = 1769104416,
  sdio_irq_thread = 0x6365707320726576,
  sdio_irq_work = {
    work = {
      data = {
        counter = 7309464380119803497
      },
      entry = {
        next = 0xa6e6f69746172,
        prev = 0x6d00000000000000
      },
      func = 0x6d00006b6c62636d
    },
    timer = {
      entry = {
        next = 0x6b636f6c625f636d,
        pprev = 0x6400000000000000
      },
      expires = 7867634009205270898,
      function = 0x2f65726f632f636d,
      flags = 1668246626
    },
    wq = 0x6d00000000000000,
    cpu = 1918853997
  },
  sdio_irq_pending = false,
  sdio_irq_thread_abort = {
    counter = 1392508928
  },
  pm_flags = 842026309,
  led = 0x5300004734304d45,
  supply = {
    vmmc = 0x5300004738304d45,
    vqmmc = 0x5300004736314d45
  },
  debugfs_root = 0x5300004732334d45,
  ongoing_mrq = 0x530032332d424d44,
  actual_clock = 858803524,
  slotno = 1291845682,
  dsr_req = 942687053,
  dsr = 1291845703,
  cqe_ops = 0x4d0000473631434d,
  cqe_private = 0x410000473233434d,
  cqe_qdepth = 1146298438,
  cqe_enabled = false,
  cqe_on = false,
  ever_unplugged = false,
  hsq_enabled = 65,
  private = 0xffffffe0007b7b19
}



Is this expected

The kernel is compiled with optimization on. And that can cause all kinds of artifacts during debugging.
It's possible that the variable host has not yet been assigned the value, and thus points to random address. To be sure, you should examine assembly instructions and confirm that the kzalloc has actually been called and the result has been assigned to the variable.
Related questions: 1, 2.

I have encountered other really weird situations. For example, after override_timeout_clk = host->timeout_clk is executed, p override_timeout_clk produces 0 but p host->timeout_clk produces an insanely large value 622869092. Is this also due to optimization?

You can't compile the kernel without optimization, but you can disable optimization for specific functions. You could try that and see if it changes the behavior you're seeing.
